# Are we allowed to ask for critiques or opinions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Couldnt find any documentation on this, but are we allowed to say post a paragraph of our writing for the community to look at and point out say errors, better word choice, sentence formatting, etc?

Answer (score 10):

This would be better suited for https://writers.stackexchange.com/

See the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq)

> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - Please proofread my document ("are there any mistakes in this text?")
> - How to improve my English

Comment: Oh nice, forgot this existed!